# Can not read a string that includes a backslash from an sql table

Tags: c#, sql, backslash

I am trying to read a string that includes a backslash in it from a sql table. For some reason I can not pass the back slash within the string. 
My string is the user name and its in this format: Domain\username
I send it to the table as so:

```
    SqlCommand scomm = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader sr;
    string nameOfUser = "Domain\userName";
        scomm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tableOfUsers WHERE UserName=" + nameOfUser;
sr = scomm.ExecuteReader();
```

During the debug I can see that another backslash is added as an escape character however I don't know what happens with the sql part and why an exception is thrown. I tried using @ but that didn't help either. 
I would appreciate any help you can provide me.

Comment: When you say "an exception is thrown" or "I get an error", the **very next thing** your fingers should start typing is the **exact** error or exception message you get. We can't see your screen from here, and can't read your mind either.

Comment: Here is the error I was getting: "Incorrect syntax near '\'."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `SqlParameter`.

```
string nameOfUser = @"Domain\userName";
scomm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tableOfUsers WHERE UserName=@username";
scomm.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=nameOfUser;
//open the connection
SqlDataReader sr=scomm.ExecuteReader();
if(sr.Read())  // use while loop when one or more exists
 {
    Console.WriteLine(sr["columnName"] + " or use column ordinal : " + sr[0]);
 }
```

Comment: +1 - I've never seen that syntax before `.Add(...).Value = nameOfUser` - cool

Comment: Thanks AVD, I tried this and Now I get this exception: "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present." And there is data in the table. I also check connection state and it is open before I execute read.

Comment: @user1094315 - You must have to call DataReader.Read() method - This method fetch a row and return true if it has data.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a string literal

```
string nameOfUser = @"Domain\userName";
```

or escape your backslash

```
string nameOfUser = "Domain\\userName";
```

---

Your query also has some errors in it.  You theoretically need to put quotes around nameOfUser

```
string nameOfUser = @"Domain\userName";
scomm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tableOfUsers WHERE UserName= '" + nameOfUser + "'";
```

But you should **really** use a parameterized query

```
string nameOfUser = @"Domain\userName";
scomm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tableOfUsers WHERE UserName= @name";
scomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameOfUser);
```

This will protect your against [Sql Injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/), and, more mundanely, will allow your query to work with people whose names have a `'`—like "O'Reilly"

Comment: Thanks Adam, same as what I mentioned above I tried this and Now I get this exception: "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present." And there is data in the table. I also check connection state and it is open before I execute read.

Comment: @user1094315 - not sure.  There's some problem with how you're executing and reading from your ado.net object.  I would post a new question with your updated code.

Comment: I found the issue. Problem was the table I was trying read from. After changing to a different table didn't have any issue reading. I suppose there was some corrupted data. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use SqlParameter.[Sql Parameter Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). as the SqlPrameter Class will provide the functionality to avoid Sql Injections and other issues, which db not allowed.

```
string UserName = @"Domain\userName";
scomm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tableOfUsers WHERE UserName=@username";
scomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",UserName);
```